# React component State clears after adding additional query parameters to the URL

Tags: reactjs, debugging, redux, react-hooks, state

In my projects I have a page which can populate data in a tab view. So the selected tab is coming as a browser history and then the next page fetches the selected tab. I'm sending following information from the page 01.

```
return ['settings', 'details', 'content'].map((menuItem) => {
  return (
    <MenuItem
      key={menuItem}
      classes={{ root: classes.menuItemRoot }}
      onClick={() => {
        handleItemClick({
          pathname: '/courses/manage',
          state: {
            activeTab: menuItem, section, id, product
          }
        });
      }}
    >
      {formatMessage(messages[menuItem])}
    </MenuItem>
  );
});
```

Then the page 2 will catch the state from browser history and load the content according to the selected tab. The URL looks like `/courses/manage`

```
  const {
    state: {
      activeTab, section, id, product
    }
  } = browserHistory.getCurrentLocation();
```

Then even after I refresh the page, the state will not be cleared.

But when I add additional query parameter like `/courses/manage?locale=fr` it renders an empty page since the state has been cleared.

So, my question is how can I make the state of the page 2 static even after changing the URL.

Comment: I want to make the state/browser history as is is even after adding some query parameters to the current URL.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely understanding what you want to do, but you can use the [`replaceState` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/replaceState) of the browser's history to replace the current state with a version that doesn't have the `state`.

Here's how with react-router-dom:

```
// access the history object
const history = useHistory();

// replace the current location with one without state
const clearState = () => {
    // get the current location which includes the state
    const {state, ...location} = history.location;
    // drop the state property and replace
    history.replace(location);
}
```